# AS3 - removeChild() removes everything from stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I'm working on a simple Flash game for school. In one level, multiple enemies spawn and the player is supposed to shoot them. I used removeChild() to get rid of the enemy that got shot, but when I click (hit) an enemy, everything on my stage gets removed; it goes completely blank.

The function to populate my stage with enemies is the following:

```
    private function Game2():void{
    for (var i:uint=0; i<50; i++) {

        var man:MovieClip = new man_mc();
        man.x=Math.random()*750;
        man.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*(70))+350;
        addChild(man);
        man.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getroffen);
    }
```

function 'getroffen' checks if an enemy got hit:

```
public function getroffen(evt:MouseEvent):void{
            trace("hit");
            this.parent.removeChild(this);

}
```

Kind of confused here as to why it removes everything on the stage instead of removing just the enemy I click on. Any help? Thanks alot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

depending on where `getroffen()` is, you're removing that class (`this` points to the current scope object), so I'm guessing it's probably the `Main` class.

You need to do something like in your remove function:

```
var man:MovieClip = evt.target as MovieClip;
man.parent.removeChild( man );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. Could you explain what the difference is with the code Tim S. provided? I understand his code better than yours, but they both seem to do the trick.

Comment: They're both functionaly equivalent. The only difference is that he uses the `currentTarget` param (probably better) instead of the `target` param. The difference comes down to how the event model works and who you register the event listener on. All i'm doing is casting the target to a `MovieClip` (you could add a check to see if it's null, then return if you want), and then calling on it's `parent` to remove it. When you add a `DisplayObject` to another one, it becomes a child of that object and has it's `parent` param set. So doing `obj.parent.removeChild( obj )` is an easy way to remove it

Comment: As for the `target` and `currentTarget` difference, the `Event` model in flash has 3 stages: the capture phase, the event phase, and the bubbling phase. When an object on the display list dispatches an event it goes `Stage->parent->parent->parent->child` where `child` is the object that dispatched the event and `parent` is each parent `DisplayObject` all the way up to the `stage`. Right up until the last `parent` we're in the capture phase. When we reach the `child`, we're in the event phase. After that, the event bubbles back up to the `Stage` again. This is the bubbling phase

Comment: So, in terms of `target` and `currentTarget`, `target` is the object that dispatched the Event, while `currentTarget` is the current object in the `Stage->parent->parent->child->parent->parent->Stage` event route.

Comment: The best way to understand what's going on, is to set up something like `Stage->Sprite->Sprite` where the last sprite has some graphics in it. Add event listeners to all the objects for something like `MouseEvent.CLICK` (i.e. to the stage, the parent sprite, and the sprite with the graphics in it). Make sure and add for both phases (the `useCapture` bool). In each listener function, trace out the `target`, the `currentTarget` and the `eventPhase`. You'll see the order things get called in, and it's much easier to understand that reading these comments :D

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `this.parent.removeChild(this)` try:

```
evt.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(evt.currentTarget);
```

That should do the trick!

The event (mouseEvent) is a 'child' of one of your enemies, so removing the target of your mouseEvent will remove the enemy.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Could you explain what the code actually means though? I understand the evt.currentTarget, but then i don't know where the 'parent' comes from. The rest is easy to understand aswell. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My apologies I havent replied to this earlier. The "currentTarget" of the MouseEvent is the object you assigned the EventListener to. Because I want to delete that object, I must first access it's parent to make it delete his children.